# How to move from one except block to another in python?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I have a function that does some FTP stuff:

```
def ftpFunc(host, user, passwd, retries=0):
    try:
        ftp = FTP(host, user, passwd)
        ... do ftp things ...
        return False, good_stuff
    except ftplib.error_temp as tmp:
        if retries >= 2:
            ... do some tidying/prep error_info ...
            return True, error_info
        return ftpFunc(host, user, passwd, retries=retries+1)
    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        ... do some tidying/prep error_info ...
        return True, error_info
```

It is expected that occasionally the FTP stuff will raise either a permanent error or a temporary error based on the servers response, in the case of a permanent (or any other) error the function returns some error value for the program to deal with but in the case of a temporary error the function recurses to retry. However I don't want the function to recurse forever so I check the number of retires and if it is too many then I return the same as in the permanent error block.

I don't mind this way but it feels "wrong" to have copy pasted code from the "all_errors" block into the temp block, I would like instead to throw the exception out of the specific temp block into the more general block after it. Is this possible?

EDIT: It seems exactly what I want isn't possible, the best alternative is to eliminate the error_temp block and instead check if e is an instance of error_temp within the all_errors block:

```
except ftplib.all_errors as e:
    if isinstance(e, ftplib.error_temp) and retries < 2:
        return ftpFunc(host, user, passwd, retries=retries+1)
    ... do some tidying/prep error_info ...
    return True, error_info
```

Comment: Your code has potential for unwanted recursion. Just use a *while True* loop and don't pass *retries* as an argument to the function

Comment: your function should do one task only of connection and related error handling to that part , and you can create a decorator to handle the error handling and  retry

Answer (score 0):

from ftplib import FTP, error_temp, all_errors

def ftpFunc(host, user, passwd, retries=0):
try:
ftp = FTP(host, user, passwd)

```
    return False, "good_stuff"
except error_temp as tmp:
    if retries >= 2:
       
        raise  # Re-raise the captured exception
   
    error_info = "Temporary error"
    raise tmp
except all_errors as e:
   
    return True, "error_info"
```

when a temporary error occurs, it captures the exception (tmp), performs the necessary tidying/preparation, and then re-raises the captured exception. This way, the exception will propagate to the more general block after the temporary error block, and you avoid duplicating code for tidying/preparation.

Comment: It does not work that way, exceptions from one `except` block aren't handled by the other `except` blocks. You need separate try-except blocks for that.